# How do I use NSManagedObject and get all the data back?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm having trouble getting my NSManagedObject to work.

In one file I have:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Location)
class Location: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var title:String
    @NSManaged var lat:NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged var lon:NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged var course:NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged var alt:NSDecimalNumber
}
```

In a TableView class I have:

```
...
var locations:NSArray = [Location]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locations = self.getAllLocations()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var logCell:TableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("loggedCell") as TableViewCell
    logCell.loggedTitle.text = locations[indexPath.row].title

    if let lat = locations[indexPath.row].lat {
        println(lat)
    }        

    return logCell
}

func getAllLocations() -> [Location] {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Locations")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) {
        return results as [Location]
    } else {
        // Failed, return empty error. Alternatively, report error.
        return []
    }

}
 ...
```

I am able to retrieve the values from CoreData. If I println( locations[indexPath.row] ) it's all there. However in func tableView I am only able to get the title. lat, lon, everything but title errors out with 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'lat', as in the lines:

```
    if let lat = locations[indexPath.row].lat {
        println(lat)
    }
```

I'm sure it's something basic as I am new to Swift and iOS development. I would appreciate a point in the right direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's partly about Swift's strict typing and partly about the interplay between Swift types and Cocoa (Objective-C) types.

The problem here is that you have typed `locations` as an NSArray. That's a Cocoa collection, not a Swift collection. Swift doesn't know what kind of thing is inside an NSArray.

*You* may know (or believe) that what's at `locations[indexPath.row]` is a Location, therefore, but Swift doesn't know that. You have to tell it, by casting (with `as`).

Alternatively, if there is no reason not to do so, type `locations` as a Swift array of Location, a `[Location]`. Now Swift knows what's in it. I should also point out that as things stand, your initializer is pointless:

```
var locations:NSArray = [Location]()
```

You start by making a Swift array of Location, yes, but then by typing `locations` as an NSArray and assigning into it, you throw away all knowledge that this thing is supposed to contain only Location objects.

Comment: Hmm, I changed it to: locations = self.getAllLocations() as [Location] but it's now erring out with "NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type" but it compiles, it errs out on the println(locations) I added to the next line.

Comment: It's telling you that something in the NSArray was _not_ a Location. It couldn't find that out until the code ran; that's why it didn't stop you at compile time. I don't know what's in your array so I can't help you. That's why I peppered my answer with a bunch of bet-hedging: notice I said "you may know _or believe_", and "if there is no reason not to do so". You mustn't lie when casting / typing; you have to really know what you've got.

Comment: It may be that you're going to want to use the `if let ... as? ...` construct to pull out an element of the NSArray and see if it really is a Location so that you can proceed without crashing.

Comment: This may seem like a pain in the butt, but the truth is that Swift is saving your butt here. Objective-C NSArray hides what's in it. It can be a mix of types. Everything comes back as an `id`, and you can crash when something is not what you were expecting it to be. Swift is much better in that it wants to perform strict type-checking for you at every possible moment.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, the CoreData coming back is not matched properly with the class Location?

Comment: I just told you, I don't have the slightest idea what's coming back. I have no reason to believe anything about what's in your array; _you_ are the one who thinks it's all Location objects. Why don't you look and _see_ what's really in there? You've got a debugger that tells you things like this...

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Xcode, swift etc. That was very helpful. I'll do that.

Comment: Core Data is no easy place to start. I sure wouldn't want to be trying to do Core Data while learning Xcode and Swift! Your courage is admirable.

Comment: Thanks! I bite off more than I can chew, then flounder around until it eventually works... Mostly thanks to kind strangers, as yourself, pointing me in the right direction.